# Use NSPredicate to search multiple fields

Tags: realm

I have a UITableView, and want to be able to search multiple property fields (in each **RMLObject** entry in an **RMLResults** array) using **NSPredicate**.  I'm attempting to do this by using '*OR*' in the predicateFormatString:

```
NSString *predicateFormat = @"(transactionDescription CONTAINS [c] %@) OR (transactionNote CONTAINS [c] %@)";

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:predicateFormat, searchText, searchText];
```

**searchText** is an NSString, and **transactionDescription** and **TransactionNote** are NSString properties in an RLMObject.

I'm passing predicate to the following REALM API call:

```
- (RLMResults *)objectsWithPredicate:(NSPredicate *)predicate;
```

However, this isn't finding the all the fields or records where searchText is part of the property.

If I limit it to just a single field(**transactionDescription**), it does find all instances:

```
predicateFormat = @"transactionDescription CONTAINS [c] %@";
```

Edited:  The following is what I now have (and still does not find all the objects that contain matches):

```
RLMResults *dataToSearch =  < code to fill dataToSearch here ... >;

// show dataToSearch

NSLog(@"dataToSearch:  %@", [dataToSearch description]);

// build predicate

NSString *predicateFormat = @"(transactionDescription CONTAINS [c] %@) OR (transactionNote CONTAINS [c] %@)";
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:predicateFormat, searchText, searchText];

// search

_searchResults  = [dataToSearch objectsWithPredicate:predicate];

// show results

NSLog(@"searchResults:  %@",[_searchResults description]);
```

The actual data has 5 instances where one or the other of the fields have a "g" in the string.  They are:

- transactionDescription:  4
- transactionNote:  1

I tried 3 different NSPredicate formats:

```
// A:

NSString *predicateFormat = @"(transactionDescription CONTAINS [c] %@) OR (transactionNote CONTAINS [c] %@)";
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:predicateFormat, searchText, searchText];

// B:

NSString *predicateFormat = @"(transactionDescription CONTAINS [c] %@)";
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:predicateFormat, searchText];

// C:

NSString *predicateFormat = @"(transactionNote CONTAINS [c] %@)";
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:predicateFormat, searchText];
```

(compound) Predicate A found:

- 1 instance in transactionDescription
- 1 instance in transactionNote

Predicate B found:

- 4 (all) instances in transactionDescription
- 0 instances in transactionNote

Predicate C found:

- 0 instances in transactionDescription
- 1 (the only) instance in transactionNote

Predicate formats B & C seem to be functioning as expected - they just search a single field, and find all instances where the string has the character 'g' in it.

While predicate A (the compound predicate) does appear to be looking at both fields, it appears to be stopping the search after finding 2 hits (missing the other 3).

I tried the ANY aggregate operator in several configurations, but all of the following NSPredicates (and several other variations) resulted in an exception when calling objectsWithPredicate:

```
@"ANY (transactionDescription CONTAINS [c] %@) OR ANY transactionNote CONTAINS [c] %@)";

@"(ANY transactionDescription CONTAINS [c] %@) OR (ANY transactionNote CONTAINS [c] %@)";

@"ANY (transactionDescription CONTAINS [c] %@ OR transactionNote CONTAINS [c] %@)";
```

Any clues on why (compound) Predicate A bails after finding just 2 hits?

Comment: Any updates on sharing an example I could use to reproduce?

Comment: yoshhosh... Can you post your sample code that works?  It might be easier for me to compare your working code (which should be much less code) against what I've got.  Hopefully I'll be able to pick out what is different with mine.

Comment: Added a sample, after trying a simple one let me know how things go!

Comment: I'm seeing that this is a bug for more complex queries, it's being tracked here https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1725

Comment: It appears this has now been fixed in version 0.92.3.  I've been regularly updating to the latest version since my original post (and checking if this is fixed), and this is the first release where it is now working.  Thanks Realm!

Comment: Great to hear! Thanks for your patience

Answer (score 3):

Joe from Realm here. This is the correct way to do it. Can you share more of your code and possibly some sample data? I just tried reproducing this on my machine and it worked without any issues.

An example, I saved several users with random names and emails, then did this predicate to search for them. It filtered out the results correctly.

```
@interface User : RLMObject
@property NSString *name;
@property NSString *email;
@end

@implementation User

@end

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];
    [realm transactionWithBlock:^{
      [realm addObject:[User createInRealm:realm withObject:@[@"Jake", @"gmail"]]];
      [realm addObject:[User createInRealm:realm withObject:@[@"Jess", @"hotmail"]]];
      [realm addObject:[User createInRealm:realm withObject:@[@"May", @"gmail"]]];
    }];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"email CONTAINS[c] %@ OR name CONTAINS[c] %@", @"gmail", @"b"];
    RLMResults *fetchedUsers = [User objectsWithPredicate:predicate];
    NSLog(@"%@", fetchedUsers);
}
```

EDIT: A comment below wanted to know how to search multiple fields

```
let searchString = "John"
let subpredicates = ["name", "firstName", "lastName"].map { property in
    return NSPredicate(format: "%K CONTAINS %@", property, searchString)
}
let predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(orPredicateWithSubpredicates: subpredicates)
let johns = realm.objects(Person).filter(predicate)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works great. If you could add some info about how to filter multiple fields with multiple words, for instance 'any word in the query can be in any field', that'd be terrific.

Comment: Sorry just saw this, updated the answer with the multiple field search

Comment: RealmSwft version 2.10.2: I found the multiple field query still wasn't working per the "EDIT:" example above until I removed "self" from the model designation, i.e. "Person.self" would break the above example. I get a warning in XCode, but the query works without Model.self. Just in case someone else gets tripped up by this.